# sql if (..) then

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

need a help :
For Example : ,(ORACLE SQL)

```
IF (a > '0') THEN 

need to do more things 

END IF;
```

i tried all possibilities , put behind THEN {} , but code wont compile .

Thanks for help.

Comment: How about googling? http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/if_then.php

Comment: Did, code wont compile ...

Comment: And what error do you receiving?

Comment: Encountered the symbol "{"when excepting one of the following : {begin case declare konec gor goto.....

Comment: you can't use `{}` in plsql. instead use the one in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing `BEGIN END block` (`anonymous block plsql`)

```
Declare
    --variable declaretion
begin
    IF a > '0' THEN 
        BEGIN
          --need to do more things 
        END;       
    END IF;
end;
```

Don't use `{}` after `then` use `begin end`.

Comment: Tried man , not work ,, i ll send little of code 
`code`
IF (...) THEN {

||text...bla bla 
}
`code`

Comment: Don't use `{}` use `BEGIN END`

Comment: and need to end a row with ; ?

Comment: `; is Statement terminator` a statement has to be terminated by `;`